# selecting latest result from a table using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

[image: Data Table]

From a `select` statement what I want is the latest unique rows (in green) for each `policy`. Some cause the `policy` information will be from the day before (all `policies` will not be published on the same day) .

In this scenario `ACB1` has changed her `last names` and `amounts` changed.

Comment: What sql-query did you try so far and what was the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get the latest row for each policy by id column:

```
    SELECT  id, policy, first, last, amount, created
    FROM    yourtable yt
            INNER JOIN
            (SELECT policy,MAX(id) as id
            FROM yourtable
GROUP BY policy) maxid ON yt.policy = maxid.policy 
                                    AND yt.id = maxid.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number` window function:

```
select * from 
  (select *, row_number() over(partition by policy order by id desc) rn from TableName) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I would use this technique as it is more clear. Also, we should check the execution plans of this query and the one from the accepted answer, but I believe this should bring better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if, instead of selecting all fields from the database, you did a `where ID=MAX()` to select the maximum ID.

So you would have:

```
SELECT `id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`policy`,`amount`,`created` 
FROM `tablename` WHERE `id`=MAX()
```